# Sorting based on First column first then second column?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a datasheet with multiple columns I want to sort on 1st column first then 2nd column. I know it is easy to do on excel but how can I do this using awk or sed?

input:

```
2    30   etc etc etc
77   5    etc etc etc
2    6    etc etc etc
39   12   etc etc etc
```

output

```
2    6    etc etc etc
2    30   etc etc etc
39   12   etc etc etc
77   5    etc etc etc
```

Entire row should follow along as it is being sorted. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use `sort(1)`? That will do it straightforwardly "A pair of lines is compared as follows: if any key fields have been specified, `sort' compares each pair of fields, in the order specified on the command line, according to the associated ordering options, until a difference is found or no fields are left. " (http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)

Comment: Most UNIX commands have an obvious name. To join files you use `join`, to paste files is `paste`, to find files is `find`, etc. So, I WONDER what the command to **sort** files would be called ...;-).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 file
2    6    etc etc etc
2    30   etc etc etc
39   12   etc etc etc
77   5    etc etc etc
```

Comment: Slight correction - that should be `sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2`. Specifying only a start field to `-k` (e.g. `-k1`) means to sort based on a key starting with field 1 and extending to the end of the line. The semantics may seem subtle, but the results can be significantly different.

Comment: +1.  Ed and @twalberg, can you explain the difference between how `sort` interprets  `sort -n -k1,2` versus `sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2`?

Comment: @John1024 `-k1,2` sorts on a single key composed of fields 1 and 2 (also note that all keys include any leading whitespace, unless you're using an alternate separator). `-k1,1 -k2,2` sorts on two keys - first on field 1, and when those entries match, it sorts on field 2. In common cases, there may not be much difference, but it's not too horribly difficult to come up with examples that seem counter-intuitive, especially regarding the "leading whitespace is part of the key" bit...

Comment: @twalberg fixed thanks. Yeah it always takes me some trial and error to get sorts arguments exactly right. Just not as intuitive to me as I expect them to be!